# Mobile nav menu

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

First let me thank you in advance.

I'm trying to make a modern burger mobile menu, to be honest i think i went in circles and now can't think how to do it.

I looking to design a mobile nav menu once media is 960px and under, later on i will add medias for smaller screen.

If you can help me create a mobile nav then  great and thank you.  Also can you look at my code to and see if its correct ie the floats in the right place, display:etc I've new to mobile menu and new to web design and i just struggle to make a menu without any issues, I suppose as there are so many methods.

Eventually I would like it to have the logo on the top and a drop down mobile menu underneath it.
    
    
    
        title

```
<body>

        <div id="Container">

            <header>
                <img id="Logo" src="images/broken3.jpeg">
                <Nav id="Nav">
                    <ul id="NavUl">
                        <li class="NavLi"><a href="#Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li class="NavLi"><a href="#Extra">Extra</a></li>
                        <li class="NavLi"><a href="#Writings">Writings</a></li>
                        <li class="NavLi"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                        <li class="NavLi"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>

                    </ul><!--End of Header-->
                </Nav><!--End of Nav-->
            </header><!--End of Header-->
        </div><!--End of Container-->




</body>
</html>



/*Body*/
 body       {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/bk1.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
    background-color: #ffffff ;
            }


 /*Default setting*/
 *          {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
            }


 /*Container (website)*/
#Container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    
}

/*Page Header*/
Header{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#000000;
}

 /*Logo div*/
#Logo{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        height:65px;
        width:auto;
        float:left;
        padding-left:20px;
}

                                            /*Navigation container*/
#Nav{

}

/*Navigation Ul*/
#NavUl{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:65px;
    border:px solid yellow;
    background-color:#000000;
    overflow:hidden;
    line-height:60px;


}

/*Navigation Li's*/
.NavLi{
    width:140px;
    background-color:#000000;
    border-bottom:px solid yellow; 
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}

/*Navigation Li's*/
.NavLi:hover{
    background-color:silver;
    border-radius:0px;
    transition: background-color .4s ease-in;
    border-bottom:5px solid purple;
}

/*Navigation LAST Li*/
#Nav li:last-child{
    border-bottom:;
}

/*Navigation a's*/
#Nav a{
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    color:White;
    font-size:1.2em;
    font-weight:500;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-decoration:none;

}


/*Navigation a's hover*/
#Nav a:hover{
    color:purple;
    padding: 0px 25px;
}

                                                        /* On smaller screens, 400px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) { 



}
```

Comment: All html tags are lower case, nav is not an exception.
Please provide a jsfiddle or codepen with a solution you've tried.
If you just want to see how bootstrap does it: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: i didn't use bootstrap, once I understand how to code it I'll give bootstrap a go

Comment: No my idea is more that you take a look at how bootstrap does it.

Comment: ok thank you, i will do that.

Comment: Here's a link to their github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3-dev/less/navbar.less#L193

Answer (score 1):

Below code working proper for mobile navigation

HTML

```
<div class="header__logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    Logo
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mobile-navigation-icon d-block d-xl-none" id="mobile-menu-trigger">
                                    <i>Menu</i>
                                </div>
    
    <!--====================  mobile menu overlay ====================-->
    <div class="mobile-menu-overlay" id="mobile-menu-overlay">
        <div class="mobile-menu-overlay__inner">
            <div class="mobile-menu-overlay__header">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-8">
                            <!-- logo -->
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    Logo
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-4">
                            <!-- mobile menu content -->
                            <div class="mobile-menu-content text-right">
                                <span class="mobile-navigation-close-icon" id="mobile-menu-close-trigger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-menu-overlay__body">
                <nav class="offcanvas-navigation">
                    <ul class="mainMenu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="has-children"><a>Dropdown menu</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="has-children"><a>Dropdown menu</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown menu</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Partner</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.mobile-menu-overlay, .page-oppen-off-sidebar {
          position: fixed;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: #333333;
          overflow: auto;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          z-index: 9999;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
          cursor: url(../images/icons/light-close.png) 16 16, pointer;
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__inner, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__inner {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(120%);
              -ms-transform: translateX(120%);
                  transform: translateX(120%);
          width: 400px;
          height: 100%;
          float: right;
          cursor: default;
          background: #CD7341;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          overflow-y: auto;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          .mobile-menu-overlay__inner, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__inner {
            width: 300px;
          }
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay.active, .page-oppen-off-sidebar.active {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay.active .mobile-menu-overlay__inner, .page-oppen-off-sidebar.active .mobile-menu-overlay__inner {
          -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
              -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
                  transform: translateX(0%);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header {
          background-color: #ffffff;
          padding: 15px 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon {
          position: relative;
          cursor: pointer;
          height: 40px;
          width: 40px;
          line-height: 40px;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:before {
          position: absolute;
          top: 23px;
          left: 8px;
          content: '';
          width: 24px;
          height: 3px;
          background: #333333;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
              -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
              -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
                  transform: rotate(45deg);
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:after, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:after {
          position: absolute;
          top: 23px;
          left: 8px;
          content: '';
          width: 24px;
          height: 3px;
          background: #333333;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
              -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
                  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
              -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
                  transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover {
          color: #CD7341;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover:before, .mobile-menu-overlay__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover:after, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__header .mobile-navigation-close-icon:hover:after {
          -webkit-transform: none;
              -ms-transform: none;
                  transform: none;
        }
            
                .mobile-menu-overlay__body, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body {
          padding: 20px 40px 100px;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation {
          /* onepage style */
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li {
          border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li > a, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li > a {
          display: block;
          color: #ffffff;
          padding-top: 18px;
          padding-bottom: 18px;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 500;
          line-height: 1.5;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li > a:hover, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li > a:hover {
          color: #ffffff;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li:last-child, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li:last-child {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children {
          position: relative;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before {
          content: '\f106';
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 12px;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 40px;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand:hover, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand:hover {
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .menu-expand:before {
          content: '\f107';
          font-size: 18px;
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu {
          padding: 12px 0 14px 10px;
          border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li {
          border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li a, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li a {
          display: block;
          font-size: 15px;
          color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
          font-weight: 500;
          line-height: 1.5;
          padding: 10px 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li a:hover, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li a:hover {
          color: #ffffff;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li:last-child, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li:last-child {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children {
          position: relative;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before {
          content: "\f106";
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand {
          position: absolute;
          right: 0;
          top: 6px;
          width: 30px;
          height: 30px;
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 30px;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:hover, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:hover {
          background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:before {
          content: '\f107';
          font-size: 16px;
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
          font-weight: 500;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children {
          position: relative;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children.active .menu-expand:before {
          content: "\f106";
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:before, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation > ul > li.has-children .sub-menu .sub-menu li.has-children .menu-expand:before {
          content: '\f107';
          font-size: 16px;
          font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
          font-weight: 500;
        }

        .mobile-menu-overlay__body .offcanvas-navigation--onepage > ul > li.active > a, .page-oppen-off-sidebar__body .offcanvas-navigation--onepage > ul > li.active > a {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
```

JS

```
var $body = $('body');
        $("#mobile-menu-trigger").on('click', function(){
            $("#mobile-menu-overlay").addClass("active");
            $body.addClass('no-overflow');
        });
        
        $("#mobile-menu-close-trigger").on('click', function(){
            $("#mobile-menu-overlay").removeClass("active");
            $body.removeClass('no-overflow');
        });
        
        $(".offcanvas-navigation--onepage ul li a").on('click', function(){
            $("#mobile-menu-overlay").removeClass("active");
            $body.removeClass('no-overflow');
        });
            var $offCanvasNav = $('.offcanvas-navigation'),
            $offCanvasNavSubMenu = $offCanvasNav.find('.sub-menu');
        
        /*Add Toggle Button With Off Canvas Sub Menu*/
        $offCanvasNavSubMenu.parent().prepend('<span class="menu-expand"><i></i></span>');
        
        /*Close Off Canvas Sub Menu*/
        $offCanvasNavSubMenu.slideUp();
        
        /*Category Sub Menu Toggle*/
        $offCanvasNav.on('click', 'li a, li .menu-expand', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ( ($this.parent().attr('class').match(/\b(menu-item-has-children|has-children|has-sub-menu)\b/)) && ($this.attr('href') === '#' || $this.hasClass('menu-expand')) ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ($this.siblings('ul:visible').length){
                    $this.parent('li').removeClass('active');
                    $this.siblings('ul').slideUp();
                } else {
                    $this.parent('li').addClass('active');
                    $this.closest('li').siblings('li').removeClass('active').find('li').removeClass('active');
                    $this.closest('li').siblings('li').find('ul:visible').slideUp();
                    $this.siblings('ul').slideDown();
                }
            }
        });
```